# correct position of "super" in awakeWithContext, willActivate, didActivate and willDisappear

Tags: initialization, watchkit

I know that you have to write

```
    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)
// code here, after the super call
}
```

In willActivate, didActivate and willDisappear where have I got to put the code? Above or below the super.willActivate(), super.etc calls?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the boilerplate code the super is always placed first before your code.

```
    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
      super.awakeWithContext(context)
      //implement any of your code here
    }
```

This goes with all override calls for a class that you subclass. Call your super's call first and pass in the parameter if any, then implement your code. If you call the code else where in the function, you may have unexpected results or incorrect setup, but you can technically call it after your code. It is best practice to call it on the first line but it is a requirement to call it somewhere in the function.